# NPM start causes unexplained error from "gulp clean && gulp frontend && gulp dev" in package.json

Tags: json, node.js, npm, gulp, package.json

I followed this [Tutorial](https://josee.me/2016/03/30/angular2-electron-yeoman-sass-bootstrap-a-complete-guide-to-setting-up-a-new-desktop-app/#comments) until I got to the **frontend tasks** step, and that's where running NPM with **npm start** gives me following error:

[image]

I traced the problem to be either this code I changed in the package.json:

package.json: `“start”: “gulp clean && gulp frontend && gulp dev”, “build”: “gulp clean && gulp`

or the changes I've made to the gulpfile.js that follows the **frontend** section of the above tutorial: 
**Note:** I have the latest Node and NPM installed.

**ERROR CODE:**

```
 $ npm start

> my-vzlr@0.0.0 start C:\my-vzlr
> gulp clean && gulp frontend && gulp dev

[11:00:58] Using gulpfile C:\my-vzlr\gulpfile.js
[11:00:58] Starting 'clean'...
[11:00:58] Finished 'clean' after 18 ms
[11:00:59] Using gulpfile C:\my-vzlr\gulpfile.js
[11:00:59] Starting 'frontend:dependencies'...
[11:00:59] Starting 'frontend:js'...
[11:00:59] Starting 'frontend:html'...
[11:00:59] Starting 'frontend:css'...
[11:00:59] Finished 'frontend:css' after 17 ms
[11:00:59] Finished 'frontend:html' after 81 ms
[11:00:59] Finished 'frontend:js' after 94 ms
[11:00:59] Finished 'frontend:dependencies' after 117 ms
[11:00:59] Starting 'frontend'...
[11:00:59] Finished 'frontend' after 4.53 µs
[11:01:00] Using gulpfile C:\my-vzlr\gulpfile.js
[11:01:00] Starting 'dev:watch'...
[11:01:00] Finished 'dev:watch' after 17 ms
[11:01:00] Starting 'dev:serve'...
[11:01:00] Webserver started at http://localhost:8000
[11:01:00] Finished 'dev:serve' after 13 ms
[11:01:00] Starting 'dev'...
[11:01:00] Finished 'dev' after 18 µs
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1253:14)
    at listen (net.js:1289:10)
    at net.js:1399:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:65:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:84:10)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Godsnake\\AppDat
a\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-vzlr@0.0.0 start: `gulp clean && gulp frontend && gulp dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-vzlr@0.0.0 start script 'gulp clean && gulp frontend &
& gulp dev'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-vzlr package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp clean && gulp frontend && gulp dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-vzlr
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-vzlr
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\my-vzlr\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EADDRINUSE error mean that the port you are attempting to listen on is already in use.  Stop the application that is using it or pick a different port number.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but now when I type: npm start the web page pops up but it remains blank and nothing loads. What could be the issue?

Comment: Pop open the dev tools (F12 typically) for your browser and see if you are getting an error or anything is the only thing I could say for that.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer now I have a new problem when I use npm start: I get the error: Cannot Get/ Copy and Paste the code to see the image of the code running: i.is.cc/z3UCd1G.jpg

Comment: I don't actually see an error in that image, can you clarify what's happening?

Comment: I'm getting a blank page with the words: Cannot /GET  i.is.cc/z5KnXfQ.jpg

Comment: I moved my new problem to his thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111838/gulp-with-npm-start-causes-a-blank-page-with-the-text-cannot-get-when-testi

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000
```

means the port you're trying to use (here, :8000) is already busy. Do you have a previous instance of the application still running ? If yes, kill it and try again. Of not, try to see if you have another service running on that port and stop it.

Comment: Thanks for your help I moved my next problem to his thread:  I'm getting a blank page now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111838/gulp-with-npm-start-causes-a-blank-page-with-the-text-cannot-get-when-testi