# Gulp with "NPM start" causes a blank page with the text: Cannot GET / when testing Locally

Tags: json, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

I've been following this tutorial [Angular2, Bootstrap, Yeoman, Gulp, tutorial](https://josee.me/2016/03/30/angular2-electron-yeoman-sass-bootstrap-a-complete-guide-to-setting-up-a-new-desktop-app/) and I get up to the frontend task section, but then something happens when I try to test the code locally.

Whenever I use **npm start** I run the following code, but end up getting the blank webpage with **Cannot GET/**
[image]

Folder Structure:

```
> my-vzlr
> -build
> -node_modules
> -src
> --app
> ---app.js
> ---index.html
> ---main.js
> --electron
> --fonts
> --images
> --styles  
> -gulpfile.js
> -package.json
```

**Package.json:**

```
> {   "name": "my-vzlr",   "version": "0.0.0",   "private": true,  
> "scripts": {
>     "start": "gulp clean && gulp frontend && gulp dev",
>     "build": "gulp clean && gulp frontend"   },   "dependencies": {
>     "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",
>     "traceur": "0.0.102",
>     "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
>     "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
>     "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
>     "zone.js": "0.5.10",
>     "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
>     "systemjs": "0.19.6"   },   "devDependencies": {
>     "del": "^2.2.2",
>     "gulp": "3.9.0",
>     "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
>     "gulp-symdest": "^1.0.0",
>     "gulp-traceur": "0.17.2",
>     "gulp-webserver": "0.9.1"   } }
```

**Gulpfile.JS**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    del = require('del'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    traceur = require('gulp-traceur'),
    webserver = require('gulp-webserver'),
    symdest = require('gulp-symdest');

    var config = {
  sourceDir: 'src',
  buildDir: 'build',
  packagesDir: 'packages',
  npmDir: 'node_modules'
};

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return del(config.buildDir + '/**/*', { force: true });
});


// run init tasks
//gulp.task('default', ['dependencies', 'js', 'html', 'css']);

// run development task
gulp.task('dev', ['dev:watch', 'dev:serve']);

// serve the build dir
gulp.task('dev:serve', function () {
  gulp.src(config.buildDir)
    .pipe(webserver({
      open: true
    }));
});

// watch for changes and run the relevant task
gulp.task('dev:watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(config.sourceDir + '/**/*.js', ['frontend:js']);
  gulp.watch(config.sourceDir + '/**/*.html', ['frontend:html']);
  gulp.watch(config.sourceDir + '/**/*.css', ['frontend:css']);
});

gulp.task('frontend', [
  'frontend:dependencies',
  'frontend:js',
  'frontend:html',
  'frontend:css'
]);

// move dependencies into build dir
gulp.task('frontend:dependencies', function() {
  return gulp.src([
     config.npmDir + '/traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js',
     config.npmDir + '/systemjs/dist/system-csp-production.src.js',
     config.npmDir + '/systemjs/dist/system.js',
     config.npmDir + '/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
     config.npmDir + '/angular2/bundles/angular2.js',
     config.npmDir + '/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
     config.npmDir + '/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
     config.npmDir + '/angular2/bundles/router.js',
     config.npmDir + '/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
     config.npmDir + '/es6-shim/es6-shim.map'
  ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildDir + '/lib'));
});

// transpile & move js
gulp.task('frontend:js', function() {
  return gulp.src( config.sourceDir + '/**/*.js')
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: ''
    }))
    .pipe(traceur({
      modules: 'instantiate',
      moduleName: true,
      annotations: true,
      types: true,
      memberVariables: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: '.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildDir));
});

// move html
gulp.task('frontend:html', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.sourceDir + '/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildDir))
});

// move css
gulp.task('frontend:css', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.sourceDir + '/**/*.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildDir))
});
```

Comment: That means it's not finding the route (or rather, what the route is supposed to be serving), you'll have to dig into the server.js file or wherever the routing is configured to find out what it's trying to do.

If you post what your file structure looks like that will help too

Comment: I added the folder structure. The main folder is called my-vzlr - then src folder - then app folder - and finally you find the app.js, index,html, and main.js

Comment: so then after running the gulp scripts, you should see a build folder.  Make sure all the files made it into that folder

Comment: Where's the build folder? Can u elaborate on how to fix this issue I'm fairly new to npm, node and gulp

Comment: I've honestly never used a generator like Yeoman before so I'm not sure of the specifics.  But based on the gulpfile you provided I would say it should be in the root level of the project, probably at the same level as your src folder

Comment: Ok thanks I figured it out, you were right. My index,html was in the wrong folder. It should have been inside src folder instead of the app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short of it is to make sure the app is structured so Gulp can move all the files it needs to

Comment: Yes, it was my fault  I actually didn't follow the folder structure and added the index.html at the wrong place.  Thanks for your help!